# In Rails, although I set the model associations, how do I ensure a user can only create one instance of a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, resources, user-profile

I generated Users with Devise, and I created a scaffold for a resource I called Profiles. I set up my models as follows:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id" 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

I want the User to only create the profile after he creates his account, but I do not want him to be able to create additional profiles which I can do by going localhost:3000/profiles/new...how could I do this? Also, how would I route to the user's specific profile? I've spent all day trying to figure this out, please help.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     new_profile_path
    end

end
```

Profiles Controller

```
 class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]


  def show
  end

 def create
   @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)

  if @profile.save
    redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new' 

end
end 


def edit

end 
  def new
     @profile = current_user.build_profile
  end


def update
   if @profile.update(profile_params)
    redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' 

  else
    render action: 'edit' 
 end
 end

private

def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def correct_user

    redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this profile" if     @profile.user != current_user

end

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:pdescript)
end

end
```

routes.rb file:

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
 resources :posts
 resources :profiles
```

Comment: There's a number of ways you could do that, but the basic answer is if Profile.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may extend your `correct_user` method for both :new and :create method:
(or create another method and just before_action :new, :create if you want them separated)

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

def correct_user
  if @profile
    # edit / update
    redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this profile" if     @profile.user != current_user
  else
    # new / create
    redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile.id) if current_user && current_user.profile
  end
end
```